# Getting duplicate record from SQL query

Tags: sql-server

Could anyone please help me while running that query in SQL Server I'm getting a duplicate record. I even tried with both left & inner join in both scenarios for `BILL_DETAILID`, I'm getting duplicate record & also used "distinct" but still facing the same issue. I want to get rid of this.

[image]

```
SELECT
    BILL_DETAIL.id AS BILLDETAILID,
    BILL_HEADER.id AS BILLHEADERID,
    adjustment.id adjustmentID 
FROM 
    BILLHEADER 
INNER JOIN
    BILL_DETAIL ON BILL_DETAIL.billdetail2billhdr = BILLHEADER.id 
LEFT JOIN
    adjustment ON adjustment.adjustment2bill_detail = BILLDETAIL.id 
INNER JOIN
    incident ON incident.case2billhdr = BILLHEADER.id
```

Comment: A couple things here, only tag the database you need. mysql <> sql-server. And two, it looks like the `bill_detailid` and `bill_headid` are identical, so do you need the greater or lesser `adjustmentid`?

Comment: No. I just want to get single record for each n every "Bill_DetailID" even for every "Bill_DetailID" we have differnt "AdjustmentID".

Comment: For `BILL_DETAIL_ID = 697843` you have `adjustmentID = 39842, 39843`. Which one of these two values do you want to return?

Comment: The max "Adjustment ID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, try:

```
select 
   BILL_DETAIL.id as BILLDETAILID,
   BILL_HEADER.id as BILLHEADERID,
   MAX(adjustment.id) as adjustmentID 
from  BILLHEADER 
Inner JOIN  BILL_DETAIL ON BILL_DETAIL.billdetail2billhdr=BILLHEADER.id 
left join adjustment on adjustment.adjustment2bill_detail=BILLDETAIL.id 
inner join incident on incident.case2billhdr=BILLHEADER.id
group by BILL_DETAIL.id,BILL_HEADER.id
```

```
select billdetailid,
       billheadid,
       adjustmentid
from
(SELECT
    BILL_DETAIL.id AS BILLDETAILID,
    BILL_HEADER.id AS BILLHEADERID,
    adjustment.id adjustmentID,
    row_number() over(partition by bill_detail.id, bill_header.id order by adjustment.id desc) rn
FROM 
    BILLHEADER 
INNER JOIN
    BILL_DETAIL ON BILL_DETAIL.billdetail2billhdr = BILLHEADER.id 
LEFT JOIN
    adjustment ON adjustment.adjustment2bill_detail = BILLDETAIL.id 
INNER JOIN
    incident ON incident.case2billhdr = BILLHEADER.id) t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: Can't we do without Group by clause as i have more then 50 columns in that query.

Comment: @Shilpi I have updated the query, this should do the trick. In the future provide as many details as possible upfront.

Comment: Thats really work Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  select 
   SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITON BY BILL_DETAIL.id,BILL_HEADER.id ORDER BY adjustment.id DESC ),
   BILL_DETAIL.id as BILLDETAILID,
   BILL_HEADER.id as BILLHEADERID,
   adjustment.id adjustmentID 
  from  BILLHEADER 
  Inner JOIN  BILL_DETAIL ON BILL_DETAIL.billdetail2billhdr=BILLHEADER.id 
  left join adjustment on adjustment.adjustment2bill_detail=BILLDETAIL.id 
  inner join incident on incident.case2billhdr=BILLHEADER.id
)
SELECT
  *
  FROM CTE
    WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

This will return the first adjustment.id for each BILL_DETAIL.id + BILL_HEADER.id combination

Comment: Inside the `OVER` clause first comes `PARTITION BY` followed by `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Also since he wants the max `adjustmentid` you want to do `order by desc`.

Comment: I have made the corrections. Thanks, Giorgos Betsos and Simon

Answer (score 0):

You may try this script.

```
SELECT
    BILL_DETAIL.id AS BILLDETAILID,
    BILL_HEADER.id AS BILLHEADERID,
    adjustment.id adjustmentID 
FROM 
    BILLHEADER 
INNER JOIN
    incident ON incident.case2billhdr = BILLHEADER.id
INNER JOIN
    BILL_DETAIL ON BILL_DETAIL.billdetail2billhdr = BILLHEADER.id 
LEFT JOIN
    adjustment ON adjustment.adjustment2bill_detail = BILLDETAIL.id 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(adjustment.id) AS maxAdjustmentId, BILLDETAIL.id as BILLDETAIL_id  FROM BILLDETAIL
    INNER JOIN  adjustment ON adjustment.adjustment2bill_detail = BILLDETAIL.id 
    GROUP BY BILLDETAIL.id 
) AS maxAdjusment on maxAdjusment.BILLDETAIL_id = BILLDETAIL.id AND maxAdjusment.maxAdjustmentId = adjustment.id
```

Comment: Explaining briefly how this script works would make this answer more broadly helpful.